# Why is there difference between difference of System.out.println(+c1) and System.out.println("c1" = +c1)?

Tags: java, char, println

When I use:

```
char c1 = '\u534e';
System.out.println(+c1);
```

Then I get:

> 21326

But when I use:

```
char c1 = '\u534e';
System.out.println("c1 = " +c1);
```

Then I got the char printed correctly:

> c1 = 华

What's the problem?

Comment: This all boils down to what `+c1` in `System.out.println(+c1);` really is, so I guess the dupe is good here.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 scenarios in your question :

**1. System.out.println(+c1);**

Adding **+** with a char type will convert it to int, so it will call **println(int)** method of **System.out**, making it to print an integer value for that character.

**2. System.out.println(c1);**

In this case we haven't added **+**, so it is still taking as **char**, so in this case **println(char)** will be called and this will cause actual char to be printed.

**3. System.out.println("c1 = " +c1);**

When we concatenate a char type to **String**, whole concatenation will be treated as **String**, so in this case **println(String)** will be called and actual character with rest of the string get printed.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THE BRILLIANT ANSWER! But I still have a little confusion: Why "System.out.println(+c1)" made the char type to the int type? I mean when I typed with the System.out.println() format, shouldn't everything in bracket be changed to char type?